# replace the first 4 character with php

Tags: php, string

I have a string `/en/products/saucony-switchback-iso/416.html` and I would like to replace the first 4th character `/en/` with `/de/`.

The result should be `/de/products/saucony-switchback-iso/416.html`

This is what I've tried:

```
$href = "/en/products/saucony-switchback-iso/416.html";
$href_replace = substr_replace($href, "/de/", 0);
```

its only returning "/de/"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to define the length of how much you're replacing in the string, which in your case is 4 (or 3, seeing as the trailing `/` is present in both) characters.

```
$href = "/en/products/saucony-switchback-iso/416.html";
$href_replace = substr_replace($href, "/de/", 0, 4);

echo $href_replace;
```

If you don't define a length as in your example, it defaults to the entire length of the string http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

> **length**
>
> If given and is positive, it represents the length of the portion of
>   string which is to be replaced. If it is negative, it represents the
>   number of characters from the end of string at which to stop
>   replacing. If it is not given, then it will default to strlen( string
>   ); i.e. end the replacing at the end of string

Which is why you're only being left with `/de/`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace /en/, [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is a better function

```
echo str_replace("/en/", "/de/", $href);
```

Comment: could i put str_replace("/en/products/saucony-switchback-iso/416.html", "/de/", $href); - since I won't always enter /en/?

Comment: First parameter is what needs to be replaced. If you put the entire string there, the entire string will be replaced by /de/

Comment: Note this will replace all occurrences of `/en/` in the string, not just the first one. It doesn't look like this will be an issue with your particular data, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you only need to do 3 (but whatever), it's simple.

```
 echo "/de" .substr("/en/products/saucony-switchback-iso/416.html", 3);
```

Output

```
/de/products/saucony-switchback-iso/416.html
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b65d8f96937fa9fa62d7945567306eae5e28d80f)

I also think substr will be about as fast as you can get it.